# How to return an object which same property name and value as a local variable

Tags: javascript

Does anyone know how I would return the values `x`,`y`,`w` and `h`? The code below doesn't work but is an example of what I'm trying to achieve

```js
const selectorRect = (function() {
  let x = undefined;
  let y = undefined;
  let w = undefined;
  let h = undefined;
  return {
    x: x,
    y: y,
    w: w,
    h: h
  };
})();

console.log(selectorRect);
```

Comment: what exactly does not work? the code you provided works fine...

Comment: I am having difficulties understand the question. The provided code works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ES6 allows you to use shorthand property values.

```
const selectorRect = () => {
  let x = undefined;
  let y = undefined;
  let w = undefined;
  let h = undefined;
  return { x, y, w, h }
}

console.log(selectorRect())
```